# I don't want my page or console to refresh! Javascript form handling

Tags: javascript, forms, event-handling, submit, reload

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" value="Try me!">
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init(){
        var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
        form.addEventListener("submit", process, false);
    };
    function process(){
        console.log("Yikes!");
        return false;
    };
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
</script>
```

I have searched, really. I found something that works, but I've been told to use eventlisteners instead of "onsubmit" etc. I'm assuming the default behaviour on form submission is to reload the page, but I thought the return false would stop this. The code I found that works is:

```
window.onload=function() {
    document.getElementById('my-form').onsubmit=function() {
    /* do what you want with the form */

    // Should be triggered on form submit
    console.log("Yipee!");
    // You must return false to prevent the default form behavior
    return false;
  }
}
```

Any help on my learning journey much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `preventDefault` method.

```
function init(){
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
    form.addEventListener("submit", process, false);
};
function process(e){
    console.log("Yikes!");
    e.preventDefault()
    return false;
};
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" value="Try me!">
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init()
    {
        var form=document.getElementById("myForm");
        form.addEventListener("submit", process, false);
    }
    function process(e)
    {
        console.log("Yikes!");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
</script>
```

OR

```
window.onload=function()
{
    document.getElementById('myForm').onsubmit=function(e)
    {
        console.log("Yipee!");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

> You need to use **preventDefault()** to prevent the form to be submitted..